# How to check Shared Prefs when app loads?

Tags: android, authentication, android-asynctask, android-activity, sharedpreferences

I am trying to remember a user's login credentials so that after he/she logs into the application the first time, each subsequent time, it automatically logs him/her in and starts the main activity.

Right now I have two activities the Login activity and the Main app activity. When a user types in his/hers credentials, it verifies them against the DB on my server in an AsyncTask. Now I am using Shared Prefs to store the username and password and each time the app is started I want to read those prefs. If they are empty, then open the Login activity/screen, otherwise open the Main activity/screen.

This works....but it takes about 3-5 seconds before it opens the Main activity. So it starts out on the Login activity and then after 3-5 seconds it goes to the Main activity. The following code is in the Login activity....where should I put it so that it does not open the Login activity unless the prefs are blank?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.user_login);

    //keep screen on while activity is running
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginEmail);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);
    loginErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_error);

    //get username and password from preferences if they exist
    sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES, getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE);

    if (sharedPrefs.contains(UserId) && sharedPrefs.contains(Password))
    {
        inputEmail.setText(sharedPrefs.getString(UserId, ""));
        inputPassword.setText(sharedPrefs.getString(Password, ""));

        new MyAsyncTask().execute(sharedPrefs.getString(UserId, ""),    
                                  sharedPrefs.getString(Password, ""));
    }

    // Login button Click Event
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString(); 

            Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
            editor.putString(UserId, email);
            editor.putString(Password, password);
            editor.commit();

            new MyAsyncTask().execute(email, password);
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Because the login activity will run far less often at startup, it would make sense to rather add the code to the main activity - i.e. check if **not** logged in and open the login activity in that case.

Comment: I will give that a try, but since the first activity that starts in my app is the login activity, wouldn't that still open before it even gets to the main activity? Or are you saying that I should make the main activity the first one to open and check if the user is logged in, if he isn't, open the login activity? Is that a secure way to implement an app? Sorry, I'm not saying it isn't, just curious.

Comment: That is exactly what I'm saying :) And as for secure - as long as you make sure to check properly whether the user is logged in before actually running the activity's main function it should be as secure as doing it the other way around. It might even be **more** secure to have this check in your main activity so that someone could not bypass your login activity altogether.